# Error using functions from another script in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

I'm trying to get a little bit better organized in my programming, so I've decided to use multiple python files to organize my game. For some reason, I cannot use functions from another script. My main script in which I run the game is called main.py and the script I'm trying to use functions from is gamemap.py . Here is the code which I use to do this

```
import pygame,sys,time
import gamemap as g

pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))
#Pictures


enemy = pygame.image.load("enemy_reg.png")
player = pygame.image.load("player_reg.png")
player_shot = pygame.image.load("playershot.png")
enemy_shot = pygame.image.load("shot.png")
g.loadmapstuff()
```

Comment: What's the error you got?

Comment: Did you try  'sudo touch                                                                        **__init__.py'**  or if on windows create new file **__init__.py**  in the directory your files are located?

Comment: If you want to import a module, then you need name your file `__init__.py`, and put it under a folder with the name of your module. Then, from another file which is located next to that folder, you can import that module using `import` followed by the name of the folder.

Comment: The error is :                                                                                        Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ihiouh\Desktop\game\main.py", line 2, in <module>
    import gamemap as g
  File "C:\Users\ihiouh\Desktop\game\gamemap.py", line 1, in <module>
    from main import *
  File "C:\Users\ihiouh\Desktop\game\main.py", line 20, in <module>
    g.loadmapstuff()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'loadmapstuff'
[Finished in 0.8s]

Comment: Create file "***C:\Users\ihiouh\Desktop\game\\__init__.py***"

Comment: Is there anything I need to do in that file? If not then it still does not work.

Comment: Just an empty file. It's a regular script but you need no code there, leave it empty.

Comment: It works! I created __init__.py and imported it in each script. Thanks! I think someone who commented. told me to do that, but I just didn't fully understand what they were telling me what to do.

Comment: Great. Just remember to create it if using your own dirs or files as imports.

Answer (score 1):

When you create your own **module** (in your case gamemap.py) you must create and empty file call `__init__.py` inside the folder that contains your module.

With this file (`__init__.py`) python understood that this folder is a package, and then you can `import` the modules that are inside of it.

I recommend you read the official docs about this matter -> [Modules and Packages](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html)

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether the two file are in the same directory.

You can also use

```
from gamemap import loadmapstuff

loadmapstuff()
```